# vscode & python 3.9.1 - unresolved imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a script in python 3.9.1, on mac os, and several modules show a message of `unresolved import 'aioboto3'Python(unresolved-import)`

I ran `pip3` in order to install them, it seems to have installed them but the messages still appear.

vscode does display correct version on the lower left bar.
[image]

Please advise on how can I resolve this? or even if this is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem:

[image]

1. Please check whether the module "`aioboto3`" has been installed in the python environment you are using: (`pip show aioboto3`)

   [image]

   (If it does not display the module installation information, it means that the module is not available in this environment. Please open a new VS Code terminal and make sure that the terminal is using the expected python environment (`python --version`).)
2. Please reload VS Code to let it recognize that the module has been installed.

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Python Environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).